# Will 3.0 gigabit HDD work on a 1.5 gigabit controller?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

My laptop has a 120 GB HDD at 1.5gigabits/s. Actually it has some bad blocks and is very slow. I'm planning to buy a new hard disk. My question is if I buy a HDD with 3.0 gigabits/s speed, will it work on my laptop?
(My laptop is
LENOVO G430-4152 and is 3 years old. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SATA specification is backward compatible. If you buy a SATA3 disk, it will run in a normal SATA interface. And so on, and so on.

It will work, with the maximum possible speed.
1.5Gbps means 192MB/s. I doubt you will find a laptop HDD which will run faster. Maybe if you buy an SSD... maybe.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, SATA chipsets are forwards and backwards compatible, and so plugging a SATA 2 drive into a SATA 1 port will just work.

There are some motherboards where this is [not the case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_1.5_Gbit.2Fs_and_SATA_3_Gbit.2Fs), in which case the SATA2 drive can be switched down to 1.5 speeds (in most cases).

If you purchase a drive with the jumper, then it will definitely work, if you don't, it will probably work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Most hard drives have a jumper setting to limit the transfer rate to 1.5. So the specification 3.0 refers to the maximum rate, not the selectable options.